# Jquery hide / unhide div on click

Tags: jquery, xhtml

So I have some code that's like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".Hidden").hide();
            $("#Unlikely").hide();
            $(".Even").click(function(){
                jQuery(this).next(".Hidden").slideToggle(500);
            });
            $(".Odd").click(function(){
                jQuery(this).next(".Hidden").slideToggle(500);
            });
            $(".UnlikelyHeader").click(function(){
                jQuery(this).next("#Unlikely").slideToggle(500);  
            })
        });
    </script>
```

is the JSP

```
<div class="UnlikelyHeader">Unlikely to be called</div><br />

    <div id="Unlikely">
        --Stuff here
    </div>
```

The stuff with hidden / even / odd works. but I'm unable to make UnlikelyHeader drop down the "Unlikely" div which is directly below it.   I think the "(this).next is wrong, but I'm not sure what else to use?

Comment: You can use `find()` instead of `next()` to find an element inside of the container you are searching. But as answered below, since it's an ID, why not just access it directly?

Comment: This is not an answer to your problem (obviously), but please don't use capital letters in class names and id names. LOL. `class="UnlikelyHeader"` is better as `class="unlikely-header"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because next element is a `br` element, why not using ID selector?

```
$(".UnlikelyHeader").click(function(){
    $("#Unlikely").slideToggle(500);  
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's only one Unlikely div (which I assume there is, since you're using an ID instead of a class) then you should be able to just use jQuery("#Unlikely").slideToggle(500);

Answer (score 2):

If this div is the only one with an id="unlikely" you can just use:

```
$("#Unlikely").slideToggle(500);
```

you could also use:

```
jQuery(this).children("#unlikely").slideToggle(500);
```